# Reordering Collections in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a Laravel project where people can post tiles on a page then click a button to move them up or down on the page. Currently I have a table setup for tiles like so:

```
$table->string('tile_name');
$table->text('tile_rules');
$table->integer('tile_order');
```

Then on the frontend I have a button should either move the tile up or down depending which arrow you press. For my up function I thought I could just take the current order from the Tile and Add which does work in its simplest form, but my question is what is the best approach for looping back through and updating all the other tiles on the page? I think it is also fair to say there will never likely be more than ten tiles on a page that would need reordering.

I was thinking this must be do able with a foreach loop:

```
$currentOrder = $currentTile->tile_order;
foreach($Tiles as $tile) {
    Tiles::whereKey($tile->id)->update(['tile_order' => ++$order]);
}
```

but what I missing is how do I tell it to start at a particular tile and only update the tiles above or below it depending on whether or not I am moving it up or moving it down?

If someone could push me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: seems like frontend job to me, you could just swap the array element on the frontend, and if you want to save it, save the order based on the array index later to database.

Answer (score 0):

I debated handling on the frontend and allowing the user to save the order when they had completed it, but instead I created an Up and Down function that would find the item above or below it and just switch the order integer with it. This seems to work better than looping through everything and updating the count.

```
 if ($tileAbove == 0) {
        session()->flash('message', 'This Tile can not be moved any higher');
    } else {
        //Update the current Tile to the new order and tileAbove to the old order
        $tileAboveObj = $positionTiles->filter(function($item) use ($tileAbove) {
            return $item->tile_order == $tileAbove;
        })->first();
        Tiles::whereKey($currentTile->id)->update(['tile_order' => $tileAbove]);
        Tiles::whereKey($tileAboveObj->id)->update(['tile_order' => $currentTileOrder]);
    }
```

with $tileAbove just being the current tile order subtracted by 1.